# Why does printf() show unusual behaviour in recursive function?

Tags: c++, recursion, printf

I have had this type of an experience many times: Using printf() in a recursive function and the output is a random number. However, using `fflush(stdout)` fixes the output. Why does this happen? Example:

The following code is a segment tree implementation. The rangeQuery() function returns the maximum element in the given range

```
    node rangeQuery(node* tree, int root, int lml, int rml, int u, int v)
    {
        //query [u,v] where all descendants of root are in [lml,rml]

        fflush(stdout);     //<<<<------------------------------HERE
        if (u<=lml && rml<=v)
            return tree[root];

        int m=(lml+rml)/2, lc=root*2, rc=root*2+1;
        tree[root].split(tree,tree[lc],tree[rc]);

        node l,r;

        if (u <= m)
            l = rangeQuery(tree, lc, lml, m, u, v);
        if (v > m)
            r = rangeQuery(tree, rc, m+1, rml, u, v);

        tree[root].merge(tree,tree[lc],tree[rc]);

        node res;
        res.merge(tree, l, r);
        return res;
    }
    int main()
    {
        //....
        int opt,a,b;
        scanf("%d%d%d",&opt,&a,&b);
        a--;
        b--;
        node newNode;
        newNode = rangeQuery(tree, 1, 1<<n, (1<<(n+1))-1, a+(1<<n), b+(1<<n));
        printf("%d",newNode.val);
        //....
    }
```

The complete code can be found here: http://ideone.com/cTT0X3

As can be seen above, removing fflush() from the rangeQuery() function produces a garbled output, whereas using fflush() produces the correct output(3). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The question fails to state the expected results and the results obtained. The problem description consists of just the single word, "garbled", which is vague and ambiguous.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Ok, I will add some details

Comment: @Ambar you should not only add details of what you expect, but also reduce your code to the absolute essential minimum. This is way too much information on the one hand and way too little on the other hand.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I fixed it, please have a look now

Comment: This is a question about garbled output using printf and still the code only contains 1 printf() which would just produce a continuous stream of numbers without separators.  I fail to see how fflush() can solve this.

Comment: @stefaanv that is exactly what I want to know: Why does fflush() correct the output?(you can see that it does change the output from 134520512 to 3)

Comment: Removing the `fflush` has no effect. [http://ideone.com/0qi5aY](http://ideone.com/0qi5aY) The question is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notwithstanding various errors including:

- using C variable-length arrays of C++ objects within a C++ program file;
- mixing C (`scanf`) and C++ input (`cin`);
- using the internal header `<bits/stdc++.h>`,

The primary cause of the error is uninitialiased variables:

```
    node l,r;   // **** here

    if (u <= m)
        l = rangeQuery(tree, lc, lml, m, u, v);
    if (v > m)
        r = rangeQuery(tree, rc, m+1, rml, u, v);

    tree[root].merge(tree,tree[lc],tree[rc]);

    node res;
    res.merge(tree, l, r);
```

If either of the conditionals do not hold, then `l` or `r` will be uninitialised, meaning that the call to `res.merge` has undefined behavior.

Initialising them with `node l{},r{};` causes your program to output `3`, although it may well still contain other bugs.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
printf("%d",newNode.val);
```

lacks a terminating newline, so that output will be buffered until the next newline is printed, or `fflush(stdout);` is called. That might explain what you're seeing.

Comment: We'll never know, until he states what's wrong/what he expects to see!

Comment: @Poldie I edited it, I guess its more explanatory now.